# ChartJs Bar's label hiding

Tags: label, chart.js

[image: Chart]

[image: Code]

Hello guys. First time here and came because I can't handle with this text in chart.js.
I can't understand why this text is hidden.

Comment: Please add your code snippet.

Comment: add new picture
highlighted one impact to text. i tried to add padding but nothing happened

Comment: Complete code would be more helpful.